# streambuf get streampos

Tags: c++, stl, stream, streambuf

I use the C++ `streambuf` class for a compiler project and need a convenient way to get the current position in the stream.

There are two member functions, `streambuf::pubseekpos` and a `streambuf::pubseekoff`, to modify the position and I am quite confused about the absence of a `streambuf::pubgetpos` member function (or something similar) to read it.

There seem to be two possible workarounds:

1. I could save the current position in a separate variable and modify
   it manually whenever I read characters from the stream.
2. I could call `streambuf::pubseekoff(0, ios_base::cur)`, which returns
   the new stream position.

The second option seems usable but inefficient and unaesthetic for such a trivial task. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Option 2, inefficient or not, appears to be a fine option. I wouldn't be concerned about aesthetics when it comes to C++. :) Maybe the API for streambuf is a minimal API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `streambuf` doesn't have a separate interface for reading the position. However, `istream` and `ostream` do (`tellg` and `tellp` respectively).

Interestingly, the streams [use your option 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) to get their positions, so it is just fine.